# Is there any word for 'do not' or 'do not have'?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, word-usage

I was trying to test my algorithm to create sentences that express the ***lack*** of something. I found saying for instance:

> I lack 5 apples

weird as compared to

> I do not have 5 apples

While thinking about this, I noticed that the closest word to ***do not*** which is used so frequently is ***don't*** which is not really a word, neither is it accepted officially. Yet, I couldn't think of any alternative I am aware of. Could it be that there are some unpopular words for any of these? If not, do you think this is worth having a word for?

Comment: In some contexts, you could say you **lack** [whatever it is you don't have], but I don't really think this question has legs. I'd like to say it's therefore *legless*, but that doesn't exactly work.

Comment: lol. Thanks. Don't really understand how using a negation with do in do not became so popular preventing the use of something simpler with time.. a natural tendency to not believe in stuff? It was quite interesting to me though...

Comment: You might use *need;* or even *want* although using that to express a lack rather than a desire is a little archaic nowadays.

Comment: @Chibueze: I don't profess to understand why what they call "do-support" has become more popular over the centuries - but what we have now seems natural to me, obviously. You'll just have to recast your algorithm (while you're at it, include "can-support", without which I ***can't*** see it working very well! :)

Comment: You could sometimes use **be without**, but you'll have to bear in mind that *to be without child* isn't really the opposite of *to be with child*.

Comment: Where do you get the notion that ["don't"](http://www.onelook.com/?w=don%27t&ls=a) isn't really a word, or that it's not "accepted officially"? I don't understand that at all. (Don't get confused by it being a [non-standard contraction](http://www.wordnik.com/words/don%27t) of _does not_).

Comment: Some other languages have a commonly used verb which means "lack". English doesn't have such a word. We say "I don't have five apples" or "I need five more apples" or "I am missing five apples".

Comment: @PeterShor Mmm - "I don't have five apples" could mean you have ten, or one, or none. "I am missing five apples" would imply a positive absence -- somebody ate them?-- rather than a negative presence. "I am *short* five apples?"

Comment: @StoneyB: We really don't know what the OP wants to say. I gave several options, and you have suggested another very good one.

Comment: @PeterShor: Yes, the exact scenario was asking for five apples, and discovering there was no five apples. Maybe cultural background is distorting my view of English, I naturally believe that lack is used to express absence of qualities rather than items, while *don't have* is a negation of have, In fact I have no apples eventually appeared to seem a better reply. And I was also thought using *don't* in an official letter is wrong as a kid, weird huh? thanks everyone for your contributions. I really appreciate :)

Comment: Chibueze Opata Firstly, your seed (the word you started off with), which is *lack*, generally means a deficiency, a shortfall, a missing item or quantity and so on. *Lacking* is not simply the opposite of *having*. You must probably be asking -- I want to say "*I **xxx** something* " as the exact opposite of "*I **have** something* ": so, what would be the word ***xxx***?

Comment: @PeterShor don't we use *lack* to mean *lack*? I'm pretty sure it's a verb.

Comment: @Kris: Exactly! This question actually made me feel weird kinda with people finding it hard to understand the scenario I was painting*...

Comment: Chibueze Opata You can edit your question suitably if you feel so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say "I lack five apples", it means that you're *five apples short* of some requirement, e.g., there are twenty-five people coming to dinner, desert is baked apple, but you have only 20 apples. People who consistently do stupid things are said to "lack common sense".

When you say "I don't have five apples", it means that someone's asked you for five apples, e.g., on Halloween, there are five trick-or-treaters on your doorstep and you don't have an apple for each, but you don't have anything else to give them either.

Writing or saying "I do not have five apples" is really weird to me unless it's an example of how to say and write "don't" without using the contraction, which almost all native speakers use most of the time, except when they want to emphasize the negative: "No, I do *not* have five apples, contrary to your pigheaded belief that I do!"

"Don't" really is an *[official](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/don%27t)* word and has been for centuries. It's used all over the anglophone world. It's discouraged or prohibited only in formal expository prose and in classrooms run by anal-retentive prescriptivists who think it's "vulgar". One of the great achievements of the early Renaissance was publishing books and newspaper in the vulgate. The King James Bible [online](http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/) shows 4,460 instances of "don't" in its modern translation (that's official enough for many Americans).

Comment: Huh? I was taught English as a kid believing you don't use *don't* in formal letters, since it's a sort of abbreviation and as a result, I grew up to believe that it's not formal. Thanks for this though.

Comment: @Chibueze Opata: Things have changed since you learned that prohibition. They've loosened up on using contractions in many kinds of writing. By the end of the century, or maybe sooner, even publishers of formal expository prose will allow contractions in academic journals and formal texts of all kinds. They're not really abbreviations; they're shortened versions of words. They actually make reading easier (abbrevs don't), so the bias against them is really kind of stupid. I prefer a greater rather than a lesser degree of formality in my prose, but I've got no problem using contractions.

Answer (score 2):

Bill Franke explains why the negation doesn't work. The simplest solution is to turn your back on the largely obsolete “lack” (along with the entirely obsolete “want”) and say simply:

> I have 5 apples **too few**.

This has the great advantage of also giving you your algorithm for an excess:

> I have 5 apples **too many**.

And when you have exactly the right quantity:

> I have **enough** apples.

Moreover, you don't have to worry about contractions.

Comment: But I still ain't got my 5 apples...

Comment: @Jim - Count again. If you ain't got 5 you mought have 10.

Answer (score 0):

How about "I am *without* five apples"?